# Link to Website with open accordion

Tags: jquery, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I know that this has been asked before but I could not get it to work: take this website: 
http://www.rrpowersystems.com/karriere/stellenangebote/index.de.html

when I click on the first panel thing with the text ("Abschlussarbeit "Planung, Konstruktion (...)" it opens a more detailed text.

Now I would like to send this link to a friend with this panel already opened. With the inspect page tool i see that it is in the  the number that I guess is essential but I just can't construct the link that I can sent somebody.

Thanks so much!

Comment: That text isn't on the page...

Comment: my mistake, thank you for your answer! http://www.rrpowersystems.com/karriere/stellenangebote/index.de.html that was the site i meant

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question directly, the jQuery UI Accordion widget does not ship with native support for auto-opening an accordion based on a hash or querystring value that is passed in the URL. Sites that have such functionality implemented are using custom logic to make that happen.

The site you linked to does not actually use jQuery UI nor its Accordion widget. I searched the source code for the text that you mentioned, and found that it is one of the options in the SelectBox (a plugin that they are using). Unfortunately, there is also no native support for auto-selecting values based on a hash or querystring value passed in the URL.

Comment: Thank you so much! this specifically was the site i was referring to: http://www.rrpowersystems.com/karriere/stellenangebote/index.de.html

Answer (score -1):

You can add the query, ex: #triggerbtn, into the link, so it would be like this:
http://www.rrpowersystems.com/karriere/stellenangebote/index.de.html#triggerbtn

```
 <body onload="triggerMe()"></body>
 <script>
    function triggerMe() {
       var check = location.hash;
       if (check == "triggerbtn") {
           //button trigger even though you do not click on it
           $('.navimain_1').trigger('click');    
       }
    }
 </script>
```

Comment: This is not what the OP was asking for. He asked to know how he can construct a link to that page that will auto-open that accordion (though he really meant auto-select options in the SelectBox).

Comment: No, there is no way to do that, as mentioned in my post. You can't execute JavaScript on a page from the address bar. The world would be a much more dangerous (maybe more fun for some, though) place if you could ;)